# Loading Screen Until Adsense for Search Block Returns Results (using Javascript, preferably Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, adsense

I am trying to show a loading screen until a loading screen until my call to Adsense for Search is completed.

Basically, I want to have `$(".loading").hide()` occur when the contents of a specific div change. Is there a way to do this using Javascript, preferably jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an interval to check if the contents of the div change and have it fire every 100ms or so.

```
original = $('#mydiv').innerHtml;
var intervalID = setInterval(function(){
    //check div
    if(original !== $('#mydiv').innerHtml){
        $(".loading").hide();
        clearInterval(intervalID);
    }
},100);
```

Comment: I guess the part here that I am confused about is how to check if there has been a change in the div